# Windows 8.1 - "Show Desktop" rectangle has disappeared from taskbar

Tags: windows-8.1, taskbar, desktop, aero-peek

My "Show Desktop" button, the vertical rectangle at the far right of my taskbar, has completely disappeared--it was there, now it's not. My taskbar now just ends abruptly with the time/date info, and there's no space to the right of that for the "show Desktop" button.

I have the "Use peek ..." box checked in my Taskbar and Navigation properties.

Any ideas how to get this back? I used it constantly and I'm at a loss as to what has happened. Thanks!

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your corner? Because we all have the invisible button there and can't really understand your problem. thx

Answer (score 1):

It's there, but just not visible until clicked.

[image: not clicked]
[image: on click]

There's no longer a tooltip either, but it still peeks at the desktop hovering over it.

However, if this is an actual bug, the current version of Windows should always be supported. You can [have Microsoft work with you on the issue here](http://support.microsoft.com/ContactUs/TechnicalSupport#gsproductselector/productid/509).

Comment: Thanks Louis, but .... I know the button's invisible. However, that's not the problem. There is literally not even a pixel of space after the clock/date on the far right of my taskbar, and so any click brings up the calendar ... so, the space for the button has disappeared.

Comment: ... that is, there is nothing there to click, not even an "invisible" rectangle. It's like the rectangle has been shoved aside somewhere or simply, somehow, removed by something.

Comment: @Brett oh darn....well you have my apologies for the simplistic answer (I gave it after seeing you were a new user). I can't reproduce this and am not aware of a policy that would remove it (though I might be wrong). Honestly, this might be one for a Microsoft MVP or employee to have at. I think they're often one and the same.

Comment: @Brett I'm sorry your Windows is broken, but there's still Win+d!

Comment: Yeah, it's quite the mystery, and I fear I'm simply going to have to get used to the keyboard way. It's been really difficult to search for a potential solution, because most everything that comes up is just about using or not using the aero-peek option _by choice_, or not understanding how it works--not about _literal_ disappearance. I'll try your Microsoft suggestion. Fingers crossed.